# Table Layout Displaying WaitCursor Always

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I am working on project where i need to use `TableLayoutPanel` but when i run project it's showing `WaitCursor` when i bring mouse over it.

I can not change this property.I tried to change it to Default but It still remains `WaitCursor`

The Panel in which I have added `TableLayoutPanel`  showing Default cursor.
Help Me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the [UseWaitCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.usewaitcursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
TableLayoutPanel1.UseWaitCursor = false;
```

> When this property is true, the Cursor property of the control and its child controls is set to WaitCursor.

Comment: @AskThakare Then look at the parent container, like the form.  If it has UseWaitCursor set to true, then all of the child controls will have it, too.

Comment: @AskThakare This is the only way I know how to recreate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go through all the controls that you do not want the waitcursor to be used for, most importantly the form itself as it is a parent for all the controls on it, and set the UseWaitCursor property to False, and/or go to Cursors, and choose Arrow or Default.

Hope it works for you